# pandas dataframe custom imputation with nearest values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 10, 10, 22, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30], "B": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b"], "C": [2, 5, 10, np.nan, 15, 20, 35, 35, 35]})
```

so my dataframe look like this

```
Index  A   B   C
0      10  a   2
1      10  a   5
2      10  b  10
3      22  b nan
4      30  b  15
5      30  a  20
6      30  b  35
7      30  b  35
8      30  b  35
```

at the 3rd row, i would like to impute the column C based on the value in the column C that satisfied these conditions.

1. nearest value in A (include itself).  for the 3rd row, the nearest value in A for 22 is 30.  (If there is 22 in other rows then the nearest value is 22)
2. same value in B.  for the 3rd row, the value of B is b.
3. majority value in C.  for the 3rd row, we can see that row 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 are satisfied the previous 2 conditions but the majority value in C is 35.

Therefore, the expected output to be impute for the 3rd row on the column C is 35.  I can write codes in the brute force method but i'm wondering whether we can do the more elegant ways or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def findVal(row):
    iMin = (df1[df1.B == row.B].A - row.A).abs().idxmin()
    aClo = df1.loc[iMin].A
    return df1[df1.A.eq(aClo) & df1.B.eq(row.B)].C.mode().iloc[0]
```

Description:

- *row* (parameter) - A row, for which *C* value is to be found.
- *df1* - Here look for data.
- *iMin* - Row with the closest *A* is at this index.
- *aClo* - The closest value of *A*.
- The value returned:

  - Find rows with the closest *A* and same *B*.
  - From them return the most often occurring value of *C*.

Then generate *df1* - rows from *df* with non-empty values of *C*.

```
df1 = df[df.C.notna()]
```

And to fill the missing values, run:

```
df.C.update(df[df.C.isna()].apply(findVal, axis=1))
```

Description:

- *df[df.C.isna()]* - Find rows with empty values of *C*.
- *.apply(...)* - Apply *findVal* to each such row.
- The result is a *Series* with:

  - indices of rows with missing values,
  - values returned by *findVal*.
- *df.C.update(...)* - The above *Series* updates *C* column at the indicated indices.